Calculating mass flow rate from a known equation
I am trying to find the mass flow rate of air in kg/min.
The equation I have is,
$Q = K \sqrt(P \frac {\Delta H}{T})$

$Q$ = mass flow rate in kg/min
$P$ = absolute pressure
$\Delta H$ = change in pressure
$T$ = temperature in Kelvin

I got this equation from someone, but I think it is incorrect.
I think this $Q$ should be volumetric flow rate and then I have to use
$\dot m = density * Q$ to get the flow in kg/min.
Where density should be density, $ \rho= (P/R*T$)
Please verify.

Which quantity is $K$?

K is the flow coefficient of the orifice, sorry I forgot to mention.

The equation for the mass flow rate discharge from a pressurized vessel through an orifice is:
$$˙=\sqrt{2*\rho*\Delta P}$$
$$˙=\sqrt{2\frac{P}{RT}\Delta P}$$

$\dot{m}$ - mass flow rate kg/s

 = the discharge coefficient

 = the cross-sectional area of the orifice m^2

$\rho$ = the density of the air kg/m^3

$\rho \ $ can also be calculated by


$$ = \frac{P}{RT}$$

$\Delta P$ = the pressure difference between the container and the ambient air Pa
R = the specific gas constant for air (J/(mol* K))
T = Absolute temp K
P = Absolute pressure Pa

We can convert the discharge units from per second to per minute.
